# Regex email - how to allow plus symbols in email?

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, email-validation

I always find regular expressions a headache, and googling didn't really help. I'm currently using the following expression (preg_match): `/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/`

However, if I'd want to allow emails with plus symbols, this obviously won't work, eg: foo+bar@domain.com

How would I need to change my expression to allow it? Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to validate email addresses (unles you're willing to compromise) See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should just use PHPs builtin regex for email validation, because it covers all the things:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

See [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) and [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/filter_validate_email) (or https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L499 for the actual beast).

Comment: Yeap. That's a nice answer. +1

Comment: And in case you were wondering, `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` uses a regex. You can see it on http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?view=markup line 525

Comment: Thanks - awesome answer! However, it still doesn't validate foo+bar@domain.com for instance - upgrading my php as we speak so hopefully it's fixed in the latest stable release!

Comment: Sorry - it was working, I was getting the email using a $_GET - should of used %2b instead of + in the URI, filter_var is working like a dream!!!

Comment: @SamGranger: That's super odd. Just tested with PHP 5.2.0 (first version to feature `filter_var`), and it worked for my setup. It might only fail if you have a trailing newline or something. --- Ah, oh well, okay then :]

Answer (score 7):

Your [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) regex can be changed to another [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) regex:

```
/^[\w-]+(\.[\w+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/
```

which allows for the `+` character where you want it. But it's **[wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)** anyway.

Comment: this is the first time I'm giving +1 for a **wrong** answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try add `\+` into the char collection `[]` :

```
/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-\+]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)(.[a-z]{2,3})$/
```